# How to merge two dataframes on date (millisecond precision) discarding outdated entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have two time-series dataframes: `df1` and `df2`. The frequency of the observations is roughly 1 second on `df1` and 1.1 on `df2`. There are gaps in data sometimes. Suppose they look like:

`df1`

```
index_1                 | something_else_1 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:10.543 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:11.700 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:14:121 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:15.122 | ...
```

`df2`

```
index_2                 | something_else_2 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:10.432 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:11.555 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:12.622 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:13.721 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:14.911 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:16.002 | ...
```

I would like to merge them on an index in such a way that if the difference between the closest times is more than 1 second, we simply discard those observations and move on. So the resulting merged dataframe would look like this:

`merged_df`

```
index_1                 | index_2                 | something_else_1 | something_else_2 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:10.543 | 2019-10-10 13:14:10.432 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:11.700 | 2019-10-10 13:14:11.555 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:14.121 | 2019-10-10 13:14:14.911 | ...
2019-10-10 13:14:15.122 | 2019-10-10 13:14:16.002 | ...
```

i.e. we have dropped some of the observations from `df2` because there were no corresponding observations (within 1 second) in `df1`.

My current "solution" is very primitive. I merge the two (outer join) and then simply fill-forward. And this is very bad, as it does not achieve the output that I require as described above.

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Why would you do an outer join here? Don't you need a left join if you're going to throw away `2019-10-10 13:14:12.622` etc?

Comment: because for any other join, it will look for exactly the same values in the other dataframe (for index). No?

Comment: The first approach that springs to mind for me is rounding the timestamps to just 1 second precision and doing a join. Forget the milliseconds. Perhaps there's a reason you can't do that, but it's not clear to me currently why you couldn't do that. You're already looking for inexact matches

Comment: Good thinking! That should work sufficiently well for my problem. Although, it would not merge correctly the `13:14:15.122` from `df1` and `13:14:16.002` from `df2`

Comment: Sure, but your example is somewhat arbitrary in what data points just get thrown away in the first place. Depending on the data, you might also have multiple matches for a single second. I'm not going to put together an answer on that basis (it would be helpful to have included code to create those DFs rather than rely on people to make their own examples before they can even start working on the problem), but it's food for thought

Comment: Whichever two are the closest to each other, would be taken then. Thanks for your comment, I think I will actually go ahead with the rounding for now.